# Auto mapper makes error when mapping class with another class properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have following two class structures, its `CASADetialsResponse` as follows,

```
public class CASADetialsResponse
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<object> validation { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class LinkedCard
{
    public string cardNumber { get; set; }
}

public class JointParty
{
    public string jointName { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
    public string accountNickName { get; set; }
    public List<LinkedCard> linkedCards { get; set; }
    public List<JointParty> jointParty { get; set; }
    public List<object> productValidation { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
    public string valueDate { get; set; }
    public string transactionDetails { get; set; }
    public string postDate { get; set; }

}

public class Data
{
    public Account account { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> transactions { get; set; }
}
```

And the `CASADetails` class structure as follows,

```
public class CASADetails
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<object> validation { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class LinkedCard
{
    public string cardNumber { get; set; }
}

public class JointParty
{
    public string jointName { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
    public string accountNickName { get; set; }
    public List<LinkedCard> linkedCards { get; set; }
    public List<JointParty> jointParty { get; set; }
    public List<object> productValidation { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
    public string valueDate { get; set; }
    public string transactionDetails { get; set; }
    public string postDate { get; set; }

}

public class Data
{
    public Account account { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> transactions { get; set; }
}
```

When I use `_mapper.Map<CASADetialsResponse>(casaResponse);` I'm getting this error:

> Error mapping types:

> Mapping types:
> CASADetails -> CASADetialsResponse
> AccountManagement.Domain.CASADetails -> AccountManagement.Application.Dtos.CASADetails.CASADetialsResponse
> Type Map configuration:
> CASADetails -> CASADetialsResponse
> AccountManagement.Domain.CASADetails -> AccountManagement.Application.Dtos.CASADetails.CASADetialsResponse
> Destination Member:
> data

This is how I map the two classes,

```
public class CASADetailsProfile : Profile
{
    public CASADetailsProfile()
    {
        // Source -> Target
        CreateMap<CASADetialsRequest, CASADetails>();
        CreateMap<CASADetails, CASADetialsResponse>();
    }
}
```

I just commented the `public Data data { get; set; }` from the both classes, and without any error its worked. I think problem is with that line. may I know the reason? please help me

Comment: Are you sure both Dto and Response object's data properties have the same type? If they are not you should also map them.

Comment: @Eldar yes, both are same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace for Data class is different, even though their content is the same.

Delete these

[image]

and refer to source Data class namespace or

If you don't want to delete them, add the following configuration

```
public class CASADetailsProfile: Profile
{
    public CASADetailsProfile()
    {
        // Source -> Target
        CreateMap<CASADetialsRequest, CASADetails>();
        CreateMap<CASADetails, CASADetialsResponse>();

        
        CreateMap<Sources.Data, Destinations.Data>();
        CreateMap<Sources.Account, Destinations.Account>();
        CreateMap<Sources.Transaction, Destinations.Transaction>();            
        CreateMap<Sources.LinkedCard, Destinations.LinkedCard>();
        CreateMap<Sources.JointParty, Destinations.JointParty>();
    }
}
```

Change Sources namespace and Destinations namespace to the namespace that you have

Comment: Thank u, But not clear, where should i apply above configurations? `CreateMap<Sources.Data, Destinations.Data>();`

Comment: @Gamma check the updated answer

Comment: in this line `CreateMap<Sources.Data, Destinations.Data>();` what is the `sources` and `Destinations` means?

Comment: They are a placeholder for the class namespace.. you have to change it to the one you have.

Comment: but still same error occurs

Comment: can you show us the configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239224/discussion-between-ash-and-gamma).

Comment: I'm really sorry, its my bad, now working perfectly. :) but one more thing to clear, `CreateMap<Sources.Transaction, Destinations.Account>();`  is this line correct? i think u mistakenly added it? is it? and please explain  why should i add configurations as above? what is the reason to do it

Comment: sorry about that.. that wasn't intentional. You can ignore that.

Comment: asking this for my knowledge,  why did u mention to delete those classes? and in auto mapper can't I use two classes with different name spaces? is it?